# python still can't insert into database

Tags: python, mysql, database, datetime, insert

i want insert my data to my MySQL database but still can't, here is my code:

```
import ue9
d = ue9.UE9()
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
import MySQLdb

timee = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
noww = strftime(timee, gmtime())
print noww

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","temperature")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = ("INSERT INTO Mydate(datenow) VALUES(%s)",(noww))

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except:
     db.rollback()
     db.close()
```

but still can't connect to database can anyone help me ?

Comment: Could you add the traceback to your post?

Answer (score 0):

You miss a comma in the list of values:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO Mydate(datenow) VALUES(%s)",(noww,))
```